# pip3 in venv: Compiling fails with Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, gcc, pip, virtualenv

What I've done:
Downloaded and compiled Python3.9
Created a virtualenvironment, tried to install pybluez

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv --python=/home/pi/Python-3.9.1/python /home/pi/venvtest
source /home/pi/venvtest/bin/activate
pip3 install pybluez
```

I know, normally you install libpython3.9-dev package. However this is currently not available for my raspberry pi system.

I've then tried `sudo ln -s /home/pi/Python-3.9.1/Include/ /usr/include/Python3.9` because it is in include path.

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 /usr/include
```

I've even removed that link and copied all the files and folders from /home/pi/Python-3.9.1/Include/ to /usr/include/Python3.9

However I always get

```
bluez/btmodule.h:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

So whats going on here? How can that module be installed in venv?

Comment: Shouldn't `"Python.h"` be `"python.h"`?

Comment: Python.h seems correct. There is a "Python.h" in includedir, but no "python.h".

Comment: Instead of manually symlinking into `include` you should probably use `sudo make install` / `altinstall`

Comment: I don't want to install Python3.9. Original Pythonversion should be preserved. Thats why I use python virtual environment. If there's another option I'd like to try.